# How to get selected item from dropdownlistfor in edit mode in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, edit, html.dropdownlistfor

I seem to be getting an error when trying to edit a dropdown even before the page loads.  Here is the error: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The ViewData item that has the key 'Manager' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

All I am trying to do is get the selected list item from dropdownlistfor.  I want it to populate just like it does on create accept have the selected item that I selected in Create have come up in Edit.  Here is my code:

Model:

```
namespace NewHireApp1.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel;

public partial class NewHire
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Manager Email")]
    public string Manager { get; set; }
    public string Managers_Email { get; set; }
    public string HR_Emp { get; set; }
    public string Emp_FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Emp_LastName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Emp_StartDate { get; set; }
    public string Emp_OfficeLocation { get; set; }
    public string Emp_Department { get; set; }
    public string Emp_Title { get; set; }

    public SelectList ADList { get; set; }
}
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult NewHire(NewHire objadmodel)
    {
        /*Getting data from database*/
        List<ActiveDirectory> objadlist = (from data in objentity.ActiveDirectories select data).ToList();
        objadmodel.ADList = objadlist.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m.mail, Text = m.mail });
        return View(objadmodel);
    }

    public ActionResult NewHireEdit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        NewHire newhire = _entities.NewHires.Find(id);
        List<ActiveDirectory> objadlist = (from data in objentity.ActiveDirectories select data).ToList();
        newhire.ADList = objadlist.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m.mail, Text = m.mail });
        ViewBag.ADList = objadlist.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m.mail, Text = m.mail });
        if (newhire == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(newhire);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult NewHireEdit(NewHire newhire, int? id)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _entities.Entry(newhire).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _entities.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("NewHireDetails", this.RouteData.Values);
        }
        return View(newhire);
    }
```

View:

```
  <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Manager, "Hiring Manager Email:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Manager, Model.ADList, String.Empty, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "ddlAD", @style = "width:500px;", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Manager, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

What can I possibly be doing wrong that I cannot retrieve the selected item?  I am new to MVC so this is making me bonkers that I cannot figure it out for the life of me.  Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create the `SelectList` yourself. If you do that, you're responsible to selecting the right item(s). Instead, just use an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ADList { get; set; }
```

Then, in your action:

```
objadmodel.ADList = objadlist.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m.mail, Text = m.mail });
```

Also, you need to populate this property in your edit action, as well. And really you shouldn't be storing this property on your entity at all. Either use a view model or put the select list items in `ViewBag`:

```
ViewBag.ADList = objadlist.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m.mail, Text = m.mail });
```

Then:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Manager, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ADList)
```

View models are the better approach though. In general, you should avoid using `ViewBag` if at all possible, though, this narrow instance is one of the few somewhat acceptable uses.

Comment: I am still getting the same error.  I just revised my code above.  It's still not working.  I think maybe I am not putting the code in the right place.  Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks so much.  Revised code above with answer.